# Restoring postgressql installation on a new linux server

Tags: linux, postgresql, server, database-restore

I don't know how to restore postgres intallation on a new ubuntu 18.04 server. My old postgres is in a mnt partition.

I've just configured new ubuntu 18.04 server with postgresqp 11 clean installation. Now, i want to point to mnt partition with my old postgres (11 too). I try to change the data_directory of the default directory with the path `"/mnt/postgresql/11/main"` but didn't work. Any ideas?

The mnt partition contains all my databases and old info:

```
/mnt/postgresql/11/main$ ls -a

.           base          pg_dynshmem   pg_notify    pg_snapshots  pg_subtrans  pg_wal                postmaster.opts
..          global        pg_logical    pg_replslot  pg_stat       pg_tblspc    pg_xact
PG_VERSION  pg_commit_ts  pg_multixact  pg_serial    pg_stat_tmp   pg_twophase  postgresql.auto.conf
```

My default path is:

```
/etc/postgresql/11/main$ ls
conf.d       pg_ctl.conf  pg_ident.conf    postgresql.conf.save    start.conf
environment  pg_hba.conf  postgresql.conf  postgresql.conf.save.1
```

And my actual `/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf` is:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FILE LOCATIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command-line
# option or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.

#data_directory = '/mnt/postgresql/11/main' '/var/lib/postgresql/11/main'
data_directory = '/mnt/postgresql/11/main'              # use data in another directory
                                        # (change requires restart)
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf'        # host-based authentication file
                                        # (change requires restart)
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_ident.conf'    # ident configuration file
                                        # (change requires restart)

# If external_pid_file is not explicitly set, no extra PID file is written.
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/11-main.pid'                   # write an extra PID file
                                        # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
```

I need to restore all the mnt partition data and i don't know how to do that. Some help??

When I restart postgres gave me this message:

```
psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 0):

`psql` is a client utility, that does not start the postgresql service. To start PostgreSQL in Ubuntu, use the `service` command (must be root or sudo):

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Comment: I started the service and after them, I can’t see nothing